# highlight combobox item if it's text starts with the text of the combobox's textbox

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I want to highlight(make bold and change its color) all the items whose text starts with the text of the combobox's textbox.

I have tried to google the above question but I am unlucky to get any similar results which would solve my problem.

I think just a hint might be more than enough to solve this problem. Though I am a newbie. If it is possible give me a simple example.

**Update :**

Here is the code that I tried:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUnder" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects}"
            IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}"
            TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="250">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="ComboBox_PART_Editable">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

But I dont know with what should I replace `ComboBox_PART_Editable` and I don't want the whole text I just want to use `Text.StartsWith`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the items in your `ComboBox` are just plain `string` values. You will have to change that and create a class to display each item. The reason for this is that you will need some `bool` 'flag' property that you can bind to a `DataTrigger` that will highlight your entries according to your requirement. So you could do this:

```
public class CustomComboBoxItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Value { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly...
    public bool IsHighlighted { get; set; } // ... here, unlike this example
}
```

Then you'd need a collection property in your code behind or view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomComboBoxItem> Items { get; set; }
```

Again, you must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly here. Then you could bind it to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />
```

By now, this should look like a normal `ComboBox` with text entries, so we have to provide a `DataTemplate` to tell the entries to get highlighted when a condition is met... that's what the `IsHighlighted` property is for:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:CustomComboBoxItem}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to set the `IsHighlighted` properties according to your requirements. For this, we'll need to bind to the `ComboBox.Text` property so that we know what that value is in the code. For this, add another property next to the collection property and update the item's `IsHighlighted` properties inside whenever it changes:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomComboBoxItem> Items { get; set; }
public string InputValue 
{
    get { return inputValue; }
    set 
    {
        inputValue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Items[i].IsHighlighted = Items[i].StartsWith(inputValue);
        }
    }
}

...

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Text="{Binding InputValue}" ... />
```

Well that was a bit more thorough than I had intended, but there you go. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Items in my combobox are not the plain string values. I mean they are strings but its a two column combobox. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Then you already have your version of the `CustomComboBoxItem` class (obviously named something else). Just add the new properties into that class and proceed in the same way.

Comment: I have tried to implement your code. I use `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects` instead of `Items`. `GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects` is `List<GroupAndCorrespondingEffect>`. Now when I try to write the below line : `Items[i].IsHighlighted = Items[i].StartsWith(inputValue);` I get red squigly line under `IsHighlighted` and `StartsWith`. When I hover over one of them, it says me : `'GroupAndCorrespondingEffect' does not contain a definition for 'IsHighlighted' and no extension method for 'IsHighlighted' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupAndCorrespondingEffect' could be found.`

Comment: Then add that property into your class. To be honest with you, if you can't work out that error, I'm starting to regret answering your question... I've given you a full solution... *you* need to do some of the work now.

Comment: I have added that property to my class. Now I don't get any errors but when I type anything in the combobox I do not get anything highlighted.

Comment: Dude, do you think that I'm just here to do your work for you? I have spent a long time providing you with a solution here that *you* will have to adapt *on your own*... all you have to do is to follow the example that I gave you.

Comment: I am sorry sir, I have tried your example and tried to follow you as much possible. But I did not get any change to my combobox after completely following your example.

Comment: Did you implement the `InputValue` property and bind it to the `ComboBox`? Did you add the `DataTemplate` to a `Resources` section? Did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your data type class *and* the code behind or view model if you're using one?

Comment: 1) Yes, I have implemented the InputValue property and bind it to the Combobox. 2) Yes, I have added DataTemplate to the resources. I have also tried to put DataTemplate in Combobox.ItemTemplate. 3) I have Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my ViewModel. But still the problem persists.

Comment: Are any errors appearing in the Output `Window` in Visual Studio? What happens if you put a break point in the `InputValue` property setter and type a value into the `ComboBox TextBox`? Also, try changing the `Binding` to this: `"{Binding InputValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`.

Comment: No, there are no errors appearing in the Output Window. When I put a break Point in the InputValue Property and when I press any key on Combobox I get the name of the first Item that matches the input. E.g. Suppose I have 4 items starting with 'D' namely : Deposits, Direct Expenses, Direct Incomes, DutiesAndTaxes. When I press D on Combobox, the value of InputValue is Deposits. But No items in the combobox are highlighted.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for guiding me. It was my fault. I forgot to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in GroupAndCorrespondingEffect Class.